# Adobe Illustrator: How to make a transparent cutout in a shape so that the cutout can be changed in the future?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I would like to make a transparent cutout in a shape so that the position or shape of the cutout can be changed in the future.

For example, consider the black and the yellow rectangles:

[image]

I would like to use the yellow rectangle as the shape that makes a transparent cutout in the black rectangle.

Using the pathfinder tool I am able to get the "almost" wanted result:

[image]

However, the cutout is now fixed and its position or shape cannot be changed making any future changes to the cutout impossible.

**Question**: how to create transparent cutouts in shapes so that the shape or position of the cutout can be changed in the future?

Comment: Its not fixed just select it with the white arrow tool or group select tool.  Also shapebuilder can also make the shapes live read your tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to are **Compound Shapes/Paths**. There are *several* methods to create Compound Paths in Illustrator — Pathfinder, ShapeBuilder, (Object) Menu items...

They **can** be changed, actually fairly easily.

Using the **Direct Selection Tool** (White Arrow), you can select the anchors or paths of any *part* of the Compound Path and alter it. It's also possible to simply delete the inner shape, draw a new shape, select both shapes and Choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu to recreate a *new* "hole".

[image]

More resources to learn how to use Compound paths:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html
- https://illustratorhow.com/compound-path/
- https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/illustrator-in-60-seconds-compound-shapes--cms-31139